# How to display many column in one comboBox

Tags: c#

I want to display many columns in one comboBox.

I've tried this:

```
 da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from do_data",cn);
        da.Fill(dt3);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt3;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "fname+lname";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
```

But it doesn't display both columns it displays the 'ValueMember'.

How to do it?

Comment: "fname+lname" is the name of a cloumn or your attempt to show to columns as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,fname + ' ' + lname As Name from do_data",cn);
da.Fill(dt3);
comboBox1.DataSource = dt3;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
```

If you want all columns then try below

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *,fname + ' ' + lname As Name from do_data",cn);
da.Fill(dt3);
comboBox1.DataSource = dt3;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
```

Comment: one more thing i'm using that combobox for search on datagridview and i take the text from combobox and use the LIKE statement on fname an lname now it takes all the text and when i try to search it doesn't show anything cuz nothing match is there any way to take one or tow column from the combobox any suggestions ?!

Comment: i'm showing all columns but i want just fname an lname to use them in search

Comment: OK i used your solution and now the combobox display fname, lname and cash, i have datagridview i write the fname in the combobox and when text change in combobox the datagridview change its result using query contain like statement. Now when i used your solution it takes all text displayed on the combobox and all column so when it takes the text from the combobox and match it with the fname using like statement it doesn't show anything in datagridview because the combobox contain many column, i only want fname from the combobox is it clear ?!

Comment: Oh in that case you have to use id instead of fname and In sql use some join to get the fname from id of combobox..

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwxk25bd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set it as display member

```
dt3.Columns.Add("Combined", typeof(string), "fname+'  '+ fname");

comboBox1.DataSource = dt3;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Combined";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
```